# Enabling USB 2.0 on Virtualbox

Tags: usb, virtualbox, kali-linux

I'm not 100% sure if Super User is the right site to ask this question so I'm apologizing
in advance if it's not.

I need to be able to attach external HDD to this Kali Linux virtual machine. I followed a tutorial on the web but even after following it step-by-step it's still not detecting the HDD attached.

Please see below:

Installed virtualbox guest extensions pack

[image]

Enabled USB 2.0 in settings

[image]

Ran `sudo usermod -aG vboxusers mark`

[image]

then logged out and logged back in.

After launching the virtual machine it's still not detecting the HDD.

[image]

When I hover
over the USB icon it says `No device attached`. It's VirtualBox 6.1

Can anyone please tell me what's missing ?

unmounting the HDD from host machine and running `sudo fdisk -I` reveals:

[image]

The disk's capacity is 750GB so it's safe to say that Kali isn't detecting it for mounting.

Kali on VMWARE:

[image]

[image]

I tried this while the pen drive was mounted and when it wasn't mounted.

Comment: How did you add the filter? Manually or using the menu while the VM was running? It may simply be wrong. You need to check the actual VM state to see which devices are attached.

Answer (score 0):

Connect the USB drive to your machine following this tutorial below. I tried this on my own Kali machine and could see the USB key just fine.

`sudo fdisk -l` <-- to see the USB key physically. (say sdb1)

`sudo mkdir /media/usb-drive` <-- to make a mount point.

`mount /dev/sdb1 /media/usb-drive/` <-- to mount the drive.

https://linuxconfig.org/howto-mount-usb-drive-in-linux

See the two connection screenshots below: one for connecting the drive and one to see the related FDISK output.  Also see the dialogue allowing the USB Key Pass through to be connected to the Guest.

You need to ensure the drive is seen before you can mount it and see the contents. You might see slightly different dialogues in Virtual Box.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: There's a limit for how big the hardisk can be on virtual machine ? OK I'm gonna try a pen drive.

Comment: No, no difference. Pen drive with 8GB isn't detected either.

Comment: Did you connect the flash drive to the Guest via the Virtual Box Menu for this operation?  You may wish to try a trial version of VMware. This is definitely working here.

Comment: I just try to add a One TB USB drive and no go. So size is a limit.

Comment: There's a right pane with icons in `Settings --> USB` one of the icons indicating adding a USB device but when I click on it it just says "no devices available" while the pen drive is mounted.

Comment: Try VMware for this.

Comment: I'm downloading it ....

Comment: Funny, I've got the same problem with VMWare. All the relevant check boxes checked off but when I power the machine on and head over to removable devices 4 devices are listed but not the pen drive and Kali isn't detecting it either. I'm having such a good day.

Comment: I added a screen shot of selecting my USB Key (Alcor Micro) and it connects fine. So I am not sure why your system will not do this. It is very straightforward and has been part of VMware for a long time.

Comment: I added my VMWare setup.

Comment: Kali can read `ext4` file system right ?

Comment: I assume so, I have not tried EXT4.  Your chicony device is a camera I think or that kind of thing. I do not know why you do not see the USB Key. Try a USB Key formatted as FAT32 to be sure.

Comment: fat32 system made no difference. I'm gonna leave it for now as I've already killed all day on this.

Comment: Fair enough. I do not know why your machine isn't working. I have used USB pass through for a number of years and set up Kali to see / read the USB key today. Try another virtual machine to test. Make sure Kali is the full Desktop Version (there is more than one variety of Kali). I use the Full Desktop version.